# Why was my comment suggesting studying history, deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

I made a comment on [How do I maintain a region of permanent political instability?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/186519/how-do-i-maintain-a-region-of-permanent-political-instability) to the end that Europe up until WW2 is effectively the answer, and that a basic study of history would provide that information:

> You've essentially described Europe up until the end of WW2. Basic history lessons would not be wasted.

That comment was removed, and I'd like to understand why.

Comment: I made a main meta post with a proposal for a feature that might help about this. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354848/feedback-for-rude-comments

Comment: It is a reasonable comment. A little snarky, but I've seen worse.

Answer (score 3):

Posts which do not comply with our **[be nice](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)** policy can be flagged and removed.

That comment in particular did not follow the

> Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do.

Comment: I agree we need policies to keep the site civilized. The problem with application on comments is that rudeness is sometimes in the eye of the beholder, and commenters are left without a clue as to why their comments were rude. Out of curiosity, with the platform's current capabilities, would it be possible to inform Ian about what exactly in his comment was offensive?

Comment: I would also add to this that the comment wasn't really what we want comments to be - if someone has an answer, it would behoove them to write it up as an answer, rather than leaving it in a comment. This is probably a borderline case, but still - the rule of thumb is that comments on the main site should suggest improvements or request clarifications - something Worldbuilding is . . . not the best at sticking to.

Comment: I'm not going to bother writing an answer explaining European history over the past millennium, **because that's what Google's for**. Similarly, I'm not going to write an answer saying "use Google" because that will be deleted. The only appropriate vehicle for such content is a comment, and now it appears I'm not allowed to use those either. Fantastic!

Comment: @IanKemp, est modus in rebus. It's not what you say, it's how you say it.

Comment: @IanKemp, has it occured to you that not everyone on this site is based in Europe? Perhaps some basic social awareness would not be wasted. Doesn't come across well does it?

Comment: @Separatrix I was born and raised in South Africa.

Comment: @IanKemp [Dale Carnegie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People) time. You can modify the language to not offend the OP. For example: "Basic history lessons would not be wasted." comes off as curt and condescending. "OP, your question reminds me a lot of European history before WW2. This book, website, youtube video here [....] provides a quick summary of the turbulent time." doesn't do that. It's the difference between Collaboration vs Condescension.